# Broadcast foobar2000's audio output as a (local) stream

Tags: audio, streaming, raspberry-pi, foobar2000

My main entertainment machine is a windows 7 pc, where I use `foobar2000` to listen to music.

In the same network, I have a raspberry pi (with raspian), and I am curious what's the easiest way to get the music I'm listening to on the rPi.

My current rough plan is to set up a private shoutcast server (along the lines of http://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/lofiversion/index.php/t49261.html) and use `sox` on the rPi to grab the stream. Will this actually work?

Are there other ways to stream the output of my foobar to the rPi? Maybe easier ways to broadcast from foobar to sox?

I've considered samba shares, too, but this would need the maintenance of two different audio streams.

Comment: Click [this](http://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?showtopic=69664) and [that](https://timlabath.com/words/2011/01/06/streaming-my-music-over-there/)

Comment: @nixda: Thanks. I've stumbled upon UPnP before - do you know of resources how to setup the rPi as an UPnP client?

Comment: Try [VLC beta](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/667/is-it-possible-to-install-vlc) and look if [this UPnP options are present](http://superuser.com/questions/191736/how-do-i-connect-vlc-to-a-known-dlna-server)