# How to Cast to DLNA TV

Tags: windows, tv, dlna

I connected my TV with ethernet cable to my modem. And my laptop is connected via WiFi.

When I right-click on a video or image, I choose "Cast to Device" option and then my TV plays that media itself without doing something.

But I can not add any subtitles to movie files. Therefore I have to find a program to watch with subtitles. I tried VLC but it seems there is no DLNA option to stream. (I tried UDP option but It did not work)
Also in PopCorn time, I used its own casting feature but again it did not work.

I can see my TV's IP or Mac adress on Windows setting about it.

Also I tried media sharing but I do not want to copy my video files to sharing. So how can I cast my media files to my TV.

Comment: Windows Media Player on Windows 10 supports this out of the box.

Comment: [How do I connect VLC to a known DLNA server?](http://superuser.com/questions/191736/how-do-i-connect-vlc-to-a-known-dlna-server) I have connected VLC to my Xbox One many times.

Comment: @Ramhound, I think he is wanting to "push" content from VLC to his TV, this answer only shows how to use the DLNA server browsing features in VLC.

Comment: @heavyd - Which is the reason I suggest WMP first.

Comment: No, it does not work. Windows Media Player didn't open subtitle files neither srt nor sub though I installed DirectVobSub. But when I open with Movies and TV, subtitles worked but didn't work on TV.